# How to display the profile page in Modal window

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

By using ctools, i am able to display a form in modal window. 
Now i wish to display a page(the profile page) in modal window.

Below is the sample code (call by menu page callback) to display a html content in modal window, but how to display a page (user/1/profile) , i know i almost there..

any ideas?

```
function mymodule_profile_modal(  $user,$js)
{   
  $output = t('<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>');
  $title = t('Modal example');
  if ($js) {
     ctools_include('ajax');
     ctools_include('modal');
     ctools_modal_render($title, $output);
     // above command will exit().
   }  

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial might help you:
http://drupion.com/blog/10-steps-creating-ctools-modal-window-drupal-7